# Scrapy pipeline spider_opened and spider_closed not being called

Tags: python, pipeline, scrapy

I am having some trouble with a scrapy pipeline. My information is being scraped form sites ok and the process_item method is being called correctly. However the spider_opened and spider_closed methods are not being called.

```
class MyPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        log.msg("Initializing Pipeline")
        self.conn = None
        self.cur = None

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        log.msg("Pipeline.spider_opened called", level=log.DEBUG)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        log.msg("Pipeline.spider_closed called", level=log.DEBUG)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        log.msg("Processsing item " + item['title'], level=log.DEBUG)
```

Both the `__init__` and `process_item` logging messages are displyed in the log, but the `spider_open` and `spider_close` logging messages are not.

I need to use the spider_opened and spider_closed methods as I want to use them to open and close a connection to a database, but nothing is showing up in the log for them.

If anyone has any suggested that would be very useful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry, found it just after I posted this. You have to add:

```
dispatcher.connect(self.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
```

in `__init__` otherwise it never receives the signal to call it

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but where do you get the `dispatcher` variable? And how come I can't find this in http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html? :(

Comment: For this to work, you need to make sure that you import the following things:
`from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher`
`from scrapy import signals`

Answer (score 6):

Proper method names are `open_spider` and `close_spider`, not `spider_opened` and `spider_closed`. It is documented here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#writing-your-own-item-pipeline.

Comment: This is incorrect. `spider_open` and `spider_closed` are signals not methods. As documented here http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html?highlight=spider_opened#std:signal-spider_opened and here http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html?highlight=spider_closed#std:signal-spider_closed

Comment: There are methods named open_spider and close_spider, however they are not related to the question.

Comment: Right, but why do you create spider_opened and spider_closed methods in your example pipeline and expect them to be called? And why do you need to attach signals manually if there are methods that are already being called?

Comment: I want to do something when these things happen not call them

Comment: Why can't you do these things in `open_spider` and `close_spider` methods which are called when the spider is opened or closed?

Comment: Because [`spider_closed`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#scrapy.signals.spider_closed) signal provides `reason` parameter, for example.

Comment: @user the question was about why methods in the example don't work. They don't work because they're named wrongly. That's true you can also use signals, though it is a separate feature.