# Closing database connection from pipeline and middleware in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I have a Scrapy project that uses custom middleware and a custom pipeline to check and store entries in a Postgres DB. The middleware looks a bit like this:

```
class ExistingLinkCheckMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self):

        ... open connection to database

    def process_request(self, request, spider):

        ... before each request check in the DB
        that the page hasn't been scraped before
```

The pipeline looks similar:

```
class MachinelearningPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):

        ... open connection to database

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        ... save the item to the database
```

It works fine, but I can't find a way to cleanly close these database connections when the spider finishes, which irks me.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the best way to do it is to use scrapy's signal [spider_closed](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#scrapy.signals.spider_closed), e.g.:

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher

class ExistingLinkCheckMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # open connection to database

        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    def spider_closed(self, spider, reason):
        # close db connection

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        # before each request check in the DB
        # that the page hasn't been scraped before
```

See also:

- [scrapy: Call a function when a spider quits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394184/scrapy-call-a-function-when-a-spider-quits)
- [Scrapy pipeline spider_opened and spider_closed not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113275/scrapy-pipeline-spider-opened-and-spider-closed-not-being-called)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the spider_closed signal.  That's perfect - thank you!