# getting spider instance from scrapyd

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

Is there a way to get the instance of the spider that runs when you schedule a run using **scrapyd**? I need to access attributes in the spider to handle outside the run and can't use a json/csv file to do this.

Comment: I found what I needed in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113275/scrapy-pipeline-spider-opened-and-spider-closed-not-being-called) : using the spider right before the spider closes. Can anyone close this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I needed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113275/scrapy-pipeline-spider-opened-and-spider-closed-not-being-called): using the `spider_close` method to run the code I need right before the spider closes.

You need to add the following to the pipeline's `__init__` method (otherwise it never receives the `spider_closed` signal):

```
dispatcher.connect(self.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
```